# How to add extension Add global in twig

Tags: php, twig, slim

When I try add the Extension Add global in twig

```
$view = new \Slim\Views\Twig($settings['template_path'], [
    'debug' => $settings['debug'],
    'cache' => $settings['cache_path']
]);
// Add extensions
$view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
    $c['router'],
    $c['request']->getUri()
));
$view->addExtension(new \Core\TwigFunction());  
$view->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
$view = new Twig_Environment();;
$view->addGlobal('session', $_SESSION);
```

I receive:

> Call to undefined method Twig_Environment::offsetSet()

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
$view = new Twig_Environment();
```

You are overriding the `$view` variable. Delete ing that line should solve the problem as `slim/twig-view` sets up the Twig environment for you.

Comment: after add $view->addGlobal('session', $_SESSION);  code doesnt'n work